# jquery - Rowspan table in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, while-loop, tablerow

it works as .text in td

```html
   <td>'.$row["j_pic"].'</td>
```

[it works.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxbPz.jpg)

but it not works with img in td

```html
<td>'."<img src='picture/".($row["j_pic"])."' style='width:20%' />".'</td>
```

[it not works.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pacmg.jpg)

jQuery

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
var span = 1; 
var prevTD = ""; 
var prevTDVal = ""; 
$("#myTable tr td:first-child").each(function() { //for each first td in every tr 
var $this = $(this); 
if ($this.text() == prevTDVal) { // check value of previous td text
span++; 
if (prevTD != "") { 
prevTD.attr("rowspan", span); // add attribute to previous td $this.remove(); // remove current td 
} } else { 
prevTD = $this; // store current td 
prevTDVal = $this.text();
span = 1; } }); });
```

Comment: share your rendered html

Comment: Why is you example code so unclear.  Am I looking at a PHP file, or what?  You need to include more of the contextual code.  There is no way of knowing how this is being parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to compare the HTML content then use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html) method instead of [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method since [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method just returns the text content inside an element.

```
if ($this.html() == prevTDVal)
```